# Form not submitting values to POST array PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a form which can be seen below:

```
<form id="myForm" action="register.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onfocus="fieldSwap('inputhover.png')" 
        onblur="fieldSwap('inputnorm.png')"><br/>
    <input type="image" src="submitnorm.png" name="submit" id="submit" 
        alt="submit button" onMouseOver="buttonSwap('submithover.png')" 
        onMouseOut="buttonSwap('submitnorm.png')" 
        onMouseDown="buttonSwap('submitclick.png')" 
        onMouseUp="buttonSwap('submitnorm.png')"/>
</form>
```

It calls this script:

```
<?php
    require_once 'db.php';

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    echo $email;
    echo "Register form";
    $sql->$db->prepare("INSERT INTO emails SET email = :email");
    $sql -> bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql -> execute();

    // Redirect back to homepage
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
?>
```

I am getting this error:

**Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\wamp\www\Holding page\register.php on line 3**

What am I doing wrong? I understand that no index called email exists in the POST array but I am unsure why this is the case.
Thanks!

Comment: depending on your doctype you should write post small.

Comment: Use `print_r($_POST);` to check what are the values stored in `$_POST`.

Comment: Are you sure that input type image does what you want? have you tried to submit it via input type submit?

Comment: @lorey changing the input type to submit did the trick. Thanks, I'll accept as answer when you post

Comment: But he can enter it in the browser if he wants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try submitting your form via

```
<input type="submit" value="send">
```

and see if that works with `` `print_r() ``.

Sadly, I don't know why `<input type="image">` is not working for you. Try checking the doctype (must be HTML5) and your browser (too old?).

Answer (score 0):

you forget to add `value` attribute in `email` as well as if input `type=image` not working for `submit` button then you may try `type=submit`

```
<form id="myForm" action="register.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" onfocus="fieldSwap('inputhover.png')" onblur="fieldSwap('inputnorm.png')"><br/>
<input type="submit" src="submitnorm.png" name="submit" id="submit" alt="submit button" onMouseOver="buttonSwap('submithover.png')" onMouseOut="buttonSwap('submitnorm.png')" onMouseDown="buttonSwap('submitclick.png')" onMouseUp="buttonSwap('submitnorm.png')"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `<input type="image">` is part of HTML5 http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html